# Is there a way I can get an address list of all locations of chain store in my country?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to get a list of certain store chains. I am using postman, google developers, Places API. I managed to send the request but keep getting the closest store to me only.

Is there a way I can get a list of all stores in my country?

This is what I managed to come up with so far:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=walmart&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,name,geometry&locationbias=circle:radius@43.470289529000205 , -79.6868741975431&radius=100000000&key=API key
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, [findplacefromtext](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place) will take a text input and return **a (single)** place:

> A Find Place request takes a text input and returns **a place**.

If you want more that one place, your only options (now) are

- [NearbySearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby)
- [TextSearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text)

(both return up to 60 results, in groups of 20 on a "page")

That said, the places API is not intended to return **all** of anything, particularly in a country.  The maximum number of results is clamped to 60 (now that the radar search is deprecated), and none of the queries will search more than a 50 km radius (See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text#radius))